# How to get current category and its subcategories in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I know I can iterate over categories to get ids of product and load them in the view, but I would have liked to get a product collection as it is done currently in most categories/views.

in short how to get subcategory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get current category and its sub categories, you can try like this

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                </a>
                <?php if ($currentCategory && $currentCategory->getId() == $_category->getId()): ?>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                    <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                    <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                    <ul>
                                <?php foreach ($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                            <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can follow this [tutorial](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/display-categories-and-subcategories-in-magento/)

Comment: @BharatM. You can follow this tutorial to get n level of sub categories of parent category: http://magentoo.blogspot.in/2014/01/get-all-subcategories-of-parent-category-magento.html